# iOS storyboard and injecting properties

Tags: ios, dependency-injection

I'm using iOS 5 storyboard for the view control hierarchy. The problem with this is that I have a few shared controller classes that handle the business logic that I would need to inject to the view controllers. These controllers are initialized and kept in the app delegate.

For instance, I have a controller encapsulating Dropbox interaction that I'm using in some of my view controllers. I could pass the reference on with each `prepareForSegue:sender:` but this makes the whole view controller hierarchy dependent of the controllers. Also, I could use the singleton pattern but I'm not really a big fan of it.

What are my options, if I want the controllers loosely coupled? I've heard of Objection, and I'll be looking into that, but any input would be very welcome

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but hopefully it can help others.

I solved this problem using protocols and checking the object to be injected responds to certain selectors.

In the `prepareForSegue` method I do one of two things:

```
id object = segue.destinationController;
if([object conformsToProtocol:@protocol(HasApplicationManager) ]){
    [(id<HasApplicationManager>)object setApplicationManager:_applicationManager];
}
if([object respondsToSelector:@selector(setViewDelegate:)]){
    [object performSelector:@selector(setViewDelegate:)withObject:self];
}
```

The first bit checks if the destination controller conforms to a specified protocol, this is still loosely coupled because you build your application with the composition pattern.

And secondly i check for a selector, this is more informal than protocols and probably more coupled and presents more problems. But it is a way of getting around having hundreds of 'IHave...' protocols.

Comment: The problem with this is that it leaves the responsibility to the calling view controller. Consider a case where one view controller is used by multiple view controllers; this would have to be done in each of the view controllers.

Comment: That's a good thing. So each parent view controller can configure the child differently. For example if a view controller rendered a given set of objects, then parent view controllers can configure it differently. This allows for a lot of extensibility.

Comment: Configurability is nice and that's what one thing the DI framework aims for. The problem is with changes. This is basically the same as duplicating code. One other thing is that with DI it is very convenient to define the resources you need within the class and they will be provided. With this kind of manual injection it leaves much to user error. I think this could be extended to some utility that would inject the missing properties afterwards. However, I'm not sure as of yet how to implement this.

Comment: The way around that is to write helpers that can do the DI for you. Then you have a nicely configurable, reusable and extendable application with minimal code repetition.

Comment: Any ideas on how to inject properties afterwards so that this would comply with Objection?

Comment: I've never used Objection. I would suggest against using it because you might accidentally start using the Service-Locator anti-pattern. The most successful DI pattern I've worked with is the Composition-Root pattern, (google it). It essentially means you should pass everything through your controllers from the applications entry point - in iOS that's the app delegate. However back to your question: I don't understand what you mean by afterwards. `prepareForSegue` is the only time you can inject properties.